# Displaying unicode read from a file

Tags: python, unicode, tkinter

I have a text file which has some names written in unicode like:

`\u0938\u0941\u0932\u0915\u094d\u0937\u0923\u093e \u0926\u0947\u0935\u0940`

I have managed to write code to read this in as a string. What I would like to do is to put this as a label in Tkinter. Now in general I know that Tkinter label text can take a unicode as when I directly code the label with this value it depicts the write character. But when I read from a file and store it in an array it on putting on the Tkinter only shows the string value.
My question is how do I convert this string representation of a unicode back into unicode. I am using code like this. roster_hindi contains the characters.

```
name_label=unicode(roster_hindi[0], 'iso8859-6')
print name_label
L=Label(t2, text=name_label, font=("KrutiDev", 18), background='gold')    
L.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='ns')
```

This doesn't work. Any help will be deeply appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data in the text file is in the form of Unicode escape sequences. Here's how to convert it in Python 2.

```
data = '\u0938\u0941\u0932\u0915\u094d\u0937\u0923\u093e \u0926\u0947\u0935\u0940'
s = data.decode('unicode-escape')
print s
```

**output**

```
सलकषणा दवी
```

To actually read the data from a file you can do something like this:

```
with open(fname, 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
s = data.decode('unicode-escape')
print s
```

---

FWIW, here's how to do it in Python 3, which is more strict about bytes vs text strings. The cleanest way (IMHO) to do this is to read the Unicode escape sequences in binary mode:

```
with open(fname, 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()
s = data.decode('unicode-escape')
print(s)
```

This code will also work correctly in Python 2.

Comment: That worked like a charm! Really appreciate the help